# How to get overall star rating of Facebook page from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a very simple request to Facebook's Graph API using this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/1984193321812400?fields=overall_star_rating&access_token=205658113371329|gYdP-nDHNVENlwVxria21Uczgs8
```

All I want from Facebook is the `overall_star_rating` of my Facebook page. However, this is what I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/206742313468873/",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "A9XRfTkh3WR"
   }
}
```

Since I am completely new to Facebook Graph API: Is the request I am making correct or am I missing something really fundamental here?

And yes, I read [Facebook's issue report](https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/), but I don't find it very helpful since I set my app to `active` already and it's not working anyway.

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Since Facebook is undergoing major changes, they have revoked few access to non active apps. Get the access_token from any frequently used app, your Graph API call is pretty correct!

But the Page ID seems to be wrong, as it shows me error after adding a working token.

> Error : "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not
>   exist: 1984192327815400"

After changing the Page ID, and adding active app token, it shows the correct result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yeah, in fact I obfuscated the `page_id` before posting here. I don't understand what you mean by getting "the access_token from any frequently used app". I've never created any other apps before. What other app could I use (abuse?) for this purpose?

Comment: By the way, I just changed my API call above back to the *real* one.

Comment: Facebook currently not giving all API calls access to new Apps access_token, you have to wait until its resolved or any new announcement by them.